# Gradle problem in android studio when I try to run in emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-dependencies

main.dart
console

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'
  I

> Could not resolve all files far configuration ':classpath'
> Could not find com, android. tools.build: gradle-settings:7.4.
> Searched in the following locations:
> -https.1/dlagoogle.com/dU/landroid/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-settings/7.4.//gradle-settings-7.4..pom
> https./repo.naven.apache.oro//maven2/com/android/tools/build/aradle-settings/7.4./gradle-settinns-7.4..pom
> Required by:
> ion Control
> Run
> I Logcat
> IN TODO 7. Profiler
> © Problems
> App inspection
> • Dart Analysis
> 1 Terminal**strong text**